# c++ Помогите оптимизировать программу. Ограничение на время работы - 2 секунды. у меня проходит за 2.01

Tags: c++

Летом Максим съездил в Летнюю Какую-то Школу, где, помимо учёбы, ему очень запомнилась игра «Шляпа», в которую он вместе с друзьями играл всю смену. Опишем правила игры, которых они придерживались. Обратите внимание: эти правила немного отличаются от общепринятых.

Изначально в шляпу помещают некоторое количество бумажек с написанными на них словами. После этого команды из двух человек по очереди и в случайном порядке начинают отгадывать слова - один член команды объясняет другому написанное на бумажке слово, не используя однокоренные. Если партнёр отгадывает его, то команде засчитывается одно очко, слово выкидывается, а команда достаёт из шляпы новое, если у неё ещё осталось время в этом раунде. Если команда не успевает отгадать очередное слово, то бумажка на которой оно написано, возвращается в шляпу, и ход передаётся какой-то случайной команде, возможно, той же самой. Игра продолжается, пока все слова из шляпы не будут отгаданы.

Теперь Максим провёл турнир для N команд из своей школы и должен определить победителя. Он неаккуратно вёл записи игры и не отмечал, сколько слов отгадала каждая из команд, зато он записывал в хронологическом порядке каждый раз, когда какая-либо команда доставала какую-либо бумажку из шляпы. Всего таких записей M, и они следуют в хронологическом порядке. Помогите Максиму восстановить по сделанным записям, сколько слов отгадала каждая из команд.

Входные данные
В первой строке дано количество команд N и количество попыток отгадать слова M (1 ≤ N ≤ 100 000, 1 ≤ M ≤ 100 000). В следующих M строках сначала указывается номер ni команды, пытавшейся отгадать слово, а через пробел дано слово wi, написанное на бумажке. Номера команд лежат в диапазоне от 1 до N. Все слова wi состоят из строчных латинских букв и имеют ненулевую длину, не превосходящую 10 букв.

Выходные данные
Выведите в одну строку N чисел, i-ое число должно равняться количеству слов, отгаданному i-ой командой.

```
2 3
1 hat
1 shirt
2 hat
output
1 1
input 
3 2
1 mom
3 dad
output 1 0 1
```

Примечание
В первом примере первая команда отгадала слово shirt, а вторая слово hat.

Система оценки
Каждый тест в данной задаче оценивается отдельно. Решение тестируется на основном наборе тестов только при прохождении всех тестов из условия. При этом тесты из условия не оцениваются.

Подзадача 1. 1 ≤ N ≤ 2000, 1 ≤ M ≤ 2000. Каждое слово встречается только один раз. Оценивается из 20 баллов.

Подзадача 2. 1 ≤ N ≤ 2000, 1 ≤ M ≤ 2000. Оценивается из 30 баллов.

Подзадача 3. 1 ≤ N ≤ 100 000, 1 ≤ M ≤ 100 000. Оценивается из 50 баллов.
вот мой код, проходит только первые две подзадачи.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int n, m, cnt;
  string s;
  cin >> n >> m;
  map < int, set < string >> dict;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dict[i + 1] = {};
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    cin >> cnt >> s;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (dict[j + 1].find(s) != dict[j + 1].end()) {
        dict[j + 1].erase(s);
      }
      dict[cnt].insert(s);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << dict[i + 1].size() << ' ';
  }
}
```

Общая суть работы кода крайне проста - я просто создаю словарь, ключ  - номер команды, а значение ключа - сет, в котором содержатся слова, которые отгадала команда. В будущем, получая то же слово я проверяю, есть ли оно в каком-либо значении данного словаря. Если есть - убираю и добавляю это значение к последнему ключе. значения словаря - set, поскольку команда может отгадать несколько слов и поэтому я решил использовать именно его . Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ¿Зачем там map?

Comment: @user7860670 в ключи я кладу номера команды, в значения - отгаданные слова(при этом тип значений- set, тк отгаданных слов может быть несколько. Какие альтернативы, ускорящие процесс вы видите?

Comment: Избавьтесь от мапа, вы им пользуетесь как вектором фактически.

Comment: @gbg а как вы предлагаете сохранять номер команды и слово?причем так, чтобы если слово повторялось, то я смог убирать его оттуда, где оно есть за быстро

Comment: Если вы сейчас чисто механически замените мап на вектор, программа продолжит работать. Вы сейчас методами мапа *не пользуетесь* (я опираюсь на кусок кода, который вы выложили). Кстати, вы начинали программировать с Python?

Comment: Да, но задачу мне надо сдать на плюсах

Comment: Исправление применили? Получилось тест пройти?

Comment: Нет, я не понимаю, как вы хотите в векторе хранить какое-то количество слов так, чтобы было ясно, к какой команде это относится.[{abc,bca},{djjd,krkd},{...}] так?это просто же никак программу не ускорит, по-моему, работа в векторе медленнее, нежели в мапе

Comment: Так, еще одна итерация объяснений и я умываю руки. У вас сконструирован мап из сетов. При этом (здесь читайте внимательно) вы не пользуетесь функционалом мапа совсем. Обращение к элементу мапа требует многих вычислений и порчи кэша процессора,  в то время, как обращение к вектору бьет точно в цель ( и не портит кэш). Внутри вектора хорошо бы (вероятно) засадить unordered set, который тоже в среднем работает быстрее просто сета засчет того, что он кэш-френдли. Напишите вот так vector<set<string>> dict.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра днем проверю

Comment: Просто хочу отметить: в тестирующих системах обычно код "выключается" сразу после превышения ограничения времени, поэтому ваш код может на самом деле и минуту работать, просто тестсистема не дожидается его окончания и выводит, сколько проработала программа на момент выключения.

Comment: И да, у вас действительно сам алгоритм слишком медленный для прохождения последней подзадачи, так как он выполняет не менее N*M операций, то есть на максимальном тесте это получается 10^10 (на самом деле еще больше, так как эта операция - поиск в сете, который работает за логарифм от длины, но не менее какой-то константы, большей одного), что в среднем отработает за 7-20 секунд.

Comment: Для того, чтобы его оптимизировать, подумайте, не можете ли вы заранее определить, какая команда отгадала конкретное слово. Если же вы можете, то вам достаточно определить это для каждого слова, встречающегося во вводе, после чего прибавить эти слова к соответствующим командам.

Comment: Откуда эта задача?

Comment: с ресура для решения олимпиадных задач

Comment: informatics msk

Answer (score 1):

Мап ваш нужно перевернуть - сделать

```
map < string, int > dict;
```

Теперь для каждой входной строки в словарь для данного слова (ключ) записывается (обновляется) значение - номер последней команды, его получившей.

После всего проходите по словарю, и для каждого элемента инкрементируете счётчик соответствующей команды (в векторе целых длиной N).

Ваш код из коммента поправил:

```
int main(){ 
    int n,m,cnt; 
    string s;
    cin >> n >> m;
    map< string , int> dict;
    vector < int > ans(n,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin >> cnt >> s;
        dict[s] = cnt; 
    }
    for (auto& item : dict)
        ans[item.second - 1]++;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cout << ans[i] <<' '; 
}
```

[Ссылка на ideone](https://ideone.com/yqNg2O)

```
3 6
1 a
1 b
2 a
3 c
2 c
1 a

2 1 0
```

Comment: ```#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n,m,cnt;
string s;
cin >> n >> m;
map< string , int> dict;
vector < int > ans(n,0);
set < string > sss;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    cin >> cnt >> s;
    sss.insert(s);
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
        dict[s] = cnt;
}
}
for(auto l = sss.begin(); l != sss.end(); l++)
{
    ans[dict[*l] - 1]++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
{
    cout << ans[i] <<' ';
}
}``` не работает(( подскажите,что делать?

Comment: как обходить словарь, не зная ключей ? я обошел, зараняя кладя ключи в сет, но по времени снова не прошло

Comment: В комментарии код не читается, лучше редактировать свой вопрос, добавляя туда. Цикл по j был вообще лишний. Обход словаря можно, например, сделать так: `for (auto& item : dict)` Добавил в ответ